# Navbar full width & dropdown width issues

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a couple of problems to which the solution has eluded me. The first problem:

As a horizontal navbar, that section needs to span the entire width of the screen. This is all well and good on my monitor, but when I zoom in or adjust the browser width so that the horizontal scrollbar appears, the navbar background cuts off at the length equal to the browser's width. That is, no matter what the size or zoom, the navbar will span the entire visible width, but scrolling even a little to the right will show you that the navbar does not span the entire page width.

The second problem relates to the dropdown feature. At the moment, the width adjusts automatically to the width of the longest word (ie, spaces cause words to break to the next line). Firstly, how do I stop this, and secondly, is it possible to adjust the width to always be as wide as the distance between the borders to either side of the main navbar links? (EDIT: Ignore the first part of this paragraph. I accidentally deleted `white-space:nowrap` from the CSS. Second part is still an issue, though)

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5pdC/1/)

HTML:

```
<nav class="bg">
    <ul class="width nav">
        <li><span class="bord"></span></li>
        <li><a href="#">DropLink</a>
            <ul class="drop">
                <li><a href="#">LongerLinkName</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LongLink WithSpace</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span class="bord"></span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><span class="bord"></span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><span class="bord"></span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><span class="bord"></span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><span class="bord"></span></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;font-size:small;vertical-align:middle;}
a{color:#F00;text-decoration:none;}
.width{margin:0 auto;min-width:1000px;width:84%;}
.bg,.drop{background:#000;}
nav>ul{width:100%;text-align:justify;font-size:0;position:relative;}
nav>ul:after{content:"";width:100%;display:inline-block;}
nav li{list-style:none;display:inline-block;position:relative;}
nav a{display:inline-block;background:rgba(0,0,0,0);transition:background 0.2s linear;padding:8px;}
nav a:hover{background:rgba(0,0,255,1);}
.drop{position:absolute;left:-1000px;top:-1000px;opacity:0;transition:opacity .5s,top 0 .25s,left 0 .25s;border-left:1px solid #BBB;border-right:1px solid #BBB;border-bottom:1px solid #BBB;}
.nav li:hover .drop{left:0;top:100%;opacity:1;transition:opacity .5s,top 0s,left 0s;}
.bord{border-left:1px solid #000;border-right:1px solid #555;padding:7px 0;}
```

Also, while I'm at it, how come I can't get the borders to be exactly the same height as the navbar itself? If I increase the padding, it becomes a pixel too long. If I decrease the padding, it becomes a pixel too short.

Also, apologies if your browser requires prefixes in the code. I substituted prefixed CSS for a script that does it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: I'm not 100% sure what you're looking to do here, but the problem you're having appears to stem from the following:

```
.width{margin:0 auto;min-width:1000px;width:84%;}
```

Changing this line to the following resolves your issue, but may introduce other issues if you intentionally had the width set smaller:

```
.width{margin:0 auto;min-width:1000px;background:#000;width:84%;}
```

Question 2: I recently answered a very similar question at: [Li element breaking content even with display block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269435/li-element-breaking-content-even-with-display-block)

Comment: Ironically, I was mere seconds away from answering the question in that link, before you snuck in! So I just upvoted, grumbled, and left! Anyway, I just noticed my CSS now, and that would explain it. I must have accidentally deleted the nowrap at one point. Still, the issue with the width in the second part remains. As for the first question, yeah I didn't want the min width removed, as it messes with the page content. Namely, the navbar.

Comment: Hi Hiigaran: Can you look at my answer again. I've updated it to leave in the min-width.

Comment: It still has the same problem at 100% width. Once it hits that min-width and the horizontal scrollbar kicks in, the issue happens. The point of the width % and min-width px combination is to keep a space on the sides of the page for larger monitors, but as browser width, monitor size, or resolution decrease, it automatically removes that space and eventually makes the page take up the entire width, allowing people with less of a viewing space to make use of the entire area.

Comment: Hiigaran, The problem in your css is the background applies to nav. Since the element inside of nav is wider than nav, it is only partially showing the background. Attaching the background color to you .width (applied to UL) resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

For your first issue I was unable to replicate it (maybe I misunderstood you).

For your second issue you can stop the wrapping of the link in the nav with the following css:

```
.nav a {
  //other styles
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got what you're after:

HTML (removed the border li's because the parent li of the dropdowns needs to be the full width you want the dropdown to be):

```
<nav class="bg">
<ul class="width nav">
    <li><a href="#">DropLink</a>
        <ul class="drop">
            <li><a href="#">LongerLinkName</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LongLink WithSpace</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: small; vertical-align: middle;}
a {color: #F00; text-decoration: none;}
.width {margin: 0 auto; min-width: 1000px; width: 84%; }
.bg {min-width:1000px;}
.bg, .drop {background: #000;}
nav>ul {width: 100%; text-align: justify; font-size: 0; position: relative;}
nav>ul:after {content: ""; width: 100%; display: inline-block;}
nav ul li {border-right: 1px solid #555; list-style: none; display: inline-block;  position: relative; text-align:center; width:19%;}
nav ul li:first-child {border-left:1px solid #555;}
nav a {display: inline-block; background: rgba(0,0,0,0); transition: background 0.2s linear; padding: 8px;}
nav a:hover {background: rgba(0,0,255,1);}
.drop {position: absolute;left: -1000px;top: -1000px;opacity: 0;transition: opacity .5s, top 0 .25s, left 0 .25s;border-left: 1px solid #BBB;border-right: 1px solid #BBB;border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;}
 .nav li:hover .drop {left: 0;top: 100%;opacity: 1;transition: opacity .5s, top 0s, left 0s;}
nav ul ul {min-width:100%;}
nav ul ul li,
nav ul ul li a {border:0;display:block;text-align:left;white-space:nowrap;width:auto;}
```

Comment: Just so I know, what has been changed?

Comment: Added a min-width to .bg, a width and border to nav ul li, display:block, and whitespace:nowrap to nav ul ul li & nav ul ul li a, and a min-width:100%; to nav ul ul. I think that's it.

Comment: I'll play around with this for a while, just to understand it. The nowrap and block definitely work. I'll probably report back any results tomorrow. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome :) I realize I didn't explain what I was doing basically at all. Elements that are positioned absolutely base their width off of their parent element, which is why the "min-width:100%" gets things to at least be a long as the parent li. And the nowrap is pretty self explanatory and the block makes the links in the dropdown fill up the entire available space (so your hover state covers the width of the dropdown).